# CPP file compile in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a single CPP file which contains my code, however when I try to compile it specifically with build feature I can't find how and were to do it.

I tried building through solution explorer but there was no option for build

Comment: `Visual Studio` or `Visual Studio Code` 2 different products ?  If MSVS then create a new project copy your file into the project directory, it should appear in Solution Explorer.

Comment: There's Build Solution under the build menu, F7, Ctrl-B, or you can right-click the file in the solution explorer and choose compile. There's also several buttons on the build toolbar to compile.

Comment: Did you write main()? ctrl+F5 is the shortcut key for debug, I suggest you try it.

Comment: thks i ctrl f5 works as a run function for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Visual Studio's File Menu and choose:
`File Menu` -> `New` -> `Project` -> Select `C++` from the **filter** dropdown list -> Select `Empty Project` from the list below -> Click the `Next` button -> Enter the `Project Name` - > click the `Create` button.

In the `Solution Explorer` project tree:
Right-click on the `Source Files` leaf item -> Select `Add` -> Select `Existing Item` -> Browse to your `.cpp` source file -> Click the `Add` button.

Right-click on the `project's icon` ( next to the name you had given it )  in the `Solution Explorer Tree` -> select `Build`.

*Most likely you will also have to Right-click on the `project's icon` in the `Solution Explorer Tree` and select `Properties` ...and set bunch of options there.  Which ones and how is outside the scope of your question.*

Don't forget to upvote and accept this answer with the green checkmark.